# Drag, Drop, Swap, Mysql

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, drag-and-drop

I read a lot of topics similar to this, but none that work with MySql database (except for sorting example )

Here's an example that I was able to implement in my script (soccer manager)
http://jsfiddle.net/k9854/

```
jQuery.fn.swap = function(b){ 
    // method from: http://blog.pengoworks.com/index.cfm/2008/9/24/A-quick-and-dirty-swap-method-for-jQuery
    b = jQuery(b)[0]; 
    var a = this[0]; 
    var t = a.parentNode.insertBefore(document.createTextNode(''), a); 
    b.parentNode.insertBefore(a, b); 
    t.parentNode.insertBefore(b, t); 
    t.parentNode.removeChild(t); 
    return this; 
};


$( ".dragdrop" ).draggable({ revert: true, helper: "clone" });

$( ".dragdrop" ).droppable({
    accept: ".dragdrop",
    activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
    drop: function( event, ui ) {

        var draggable = ui.draggable, droppable = $(this),
            dragPos = draggable.position(), dropPos = droppable.position();

        draggable.css({
            left: dropPos.left+'px',
            top: dropPos.top+'px'
        });

        droppable.css({
            left: dragPos.left+'px',
            top: dragPos.top+'px'
        });
        draggable.swap(droppable);
    }
});
```

all is greate, when i change player (Drag, drop and swap), but, when i refresh page, my new player ordering is lost.

how to use this example with mysql database?
or
Is there any example that works with mysql database?

thanks

Comment: Normally a browser doesn't have access to a MySQL database except through AJAX. The best you can get is indexedDB (poor support) localStorage/JSON (great support) or cookies/JSON (great support, outdated API, visible by the server).

Comment: What's the sorting example you've seen? If it uses MySQL, it most likely uses AJAX as well - If so, the server needs to cooperate (what's your server-side technology)?

Comment: Can you show me an example, I'm still not so skilled with using ajax and jquery

I need this for make substitution of the player in soccer manager. For now, i make substitution with sample php, html, mysql -  combo box. It is much more beautiful and more practical when we using jquery drag drop and swap

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get the id of the draggable div

```
var drag = $('.ui-draggable').attr('id');
```

but how to get id of (target) swapped div ?

Comment: $('.ui-state-hover').attr('id');
is not what i need.
if i drag <div id="item3"> on dropped on <div id="item4">

alert($('.ui-state-hover').attr('id')); will giva me 
item5

any solution ?